# Pointer to class object in overloading prefix and postfix operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I overloaded prefix and postfix increment/decrement operators in a class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:
X() { cout << "X" << endl;}
~X() { cout << "~X" << endl; }

X& operator++() { X *x = new X; return *x; }
X operator++(int) { X *x = new X; return *x; }
X& operator--() { X *x = new X; return *x; }
X operator--(int) { X *x = new X; return *x; }
};

int main()
{
X p;
cout << endl;
++p;
cout << endl;
p++;
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
X

X

X
~X

~X
```

It seems that when using postfix increment, object gets instantiated and deleted, but when using prefix increment it doesn't get deleted.

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Why are you using `new` at all here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your postfix operators return by value, so the object you created with `new` is copied, and since you don't bind it to anything the copy gets destroyed at the end of the postfix expression in `main`. By also having the copy constructor output something you can observe this behavior, see for example [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oOT25g9nA82BlcP1).

You prefix operators on the other hand just return a reference to the object you allocated with `new`, so at the end of the expression in `main` just the reference is destroyed.

In both cases you're leaking the memory allocated by `new`.

Answer (score 1):

The postfix version returns an instance of `X`, not a reference to an instance, so the destructor of this copy is called. Anyway, you should not have to use `new` in your operators:

```
X& operator++() { return *this; }
X operator++(int) { X x; return x; }
```